# How does this action decompose into irreducible representations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory

I am considering the action of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$ given by the formula $x \mapsto y \mapsto z \mapsto x$. I want to determine its decomposition into irreducible representations, but I'm having some trouble.

I know that any representation of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ can be expressed as the direct sum of $1$-dimensional representations, but I'm having trouble understanding what to do from here. I know the $\mathbb{R}$-vector subspaces invariant under this action on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (See [What are the $\mathbb{R}$-vector subspaces invariant under this action?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107502/what-are-the-mathbbr-vector-subspaces-invariant-under-this-action)), but I don't know where to go next, or what to even write down.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint 1: the action is linear. Write down its matrix and try to diagonalize it.

Comment: Hint 2: What happens to $x+y+z$? Done that, consider the same expression with coefficients suitable third roots of $1$.

Comment: @AdLibitum The eigenvalues of the matrix by which $\mathbb{Z}/3$ acts are the three cube roots of one, so the diagonalised matrix is of the form diag$(1,\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3}), \exp(\frac{4\pi i}{3}))$. Thus the representation decomposes as $\rho = \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2 \oplus \rho_3$ where $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3$ are the 1-diml representations of $\mathbb{Z}/3$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Joe: Almost correct, but you need to consider that $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right), \exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)$ are not in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @mathreadler But aren't we working with $\mathbb{C}^3?$

Comment: If we are then yes we can further reduce  down to the complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The matrix

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]$$

represents the action if the elements x,y,z correspond to $[1,0,0]^T, [0,1,0]^T, [0,0,1]^T$. Which is the basis $\bf S$ and $\bf C$ with smallest blocks on the diagonal so that $${\bf M = SCS}^{-1}$$?

---

**EDIT**
As it seems the OP has solved the problem, some clarifications may be in order:

If we solve $\det({\bf M}-\lambda {\bf I}) = 0$ we will get the irreducible representations split in roots $\lambda$ and subspaces spanned by vectors which have no roots (in our scalar field). Over $\mathbb C$, it is easy to show that $$\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\} = \left\{1,\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i} {6}\right),\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi i} {6}\right)\right\}$$

and then the irreducible representations will correspond to the 1 dimensional eigenspaces. However if we work over $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, then we need to investigate the spaces spanned by non-real eigenvalues. If we multiply them together: $$(\lambda-\lambda_2)(\lambda-\lambda_3)=\left(\lambda - \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i} {6}\right)\right)\left(\lambda - \exp\left(\frac{-2\pi i} {6}\right)\right) = \lambda^2+\lambda+1$$

Which we see has real coefficients and for example can be put on similar form to example the factors' companion matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&-1\end{array}\right]$$

or the popular 2x2 real block representation of complex conjugates:

$$a+bi \Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc}a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right]$$

We can choose whichever is most convenient for us, but it is the size of the block that determines the size of the irreducible representation which is 2 dimensional.

---

So for the real case it is $\rho = \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2$,

where $\rho_1$ is 1 dimensional corresponding to the root $\lambda = 1$ (or linear factor $(\lambda-1)$),

and $\rho_2$ is 2 dimensional corresponding to quadratic factor $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$ which can't be factored any further (over $\mathbb R$).